# upload Video File to Firebase Storage - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, video, upload

I am trying to upload a video file to firebase storage, but I keep on getting the error : "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." But, I'm sure that my server responce is good because I can upload images with no problem.

This is how I get my video url (via uiimagepickercontroller) :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
     guard let mediaInfo = info[.mediaType] else { return }
     let mediaType = "\(mediaInfo)"
     if mediaType == "public.movie" {
        // how we handle it if it's a video
        guard let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? NSURL else {return }
        videoUrl = videoURL
   }
}
```

How I attempted to upload the video :

```
        guard let videoUrl = videoUrl else { return }
        
        let videoName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(videoName).mov")
        storageRef.putFile(from: videoUrl as URL, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
             // IMPORTANT: this is where I got the error from 
            if error != nil {
                print("error uploading video: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                // successfully uploaded the video
                storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error downloading uploaded videos Url: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        if let downloadUrl = url {
                            let contentType = "videoUrl" //just a var for the following func
                            self.uploadPost(for: downloadUrl, contentType: contentType) // func that uploads the url to the database
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

can someone help me on why this doesn't work, perhaps I need to convert the url to a mp4 file or something. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and it's really simple...
The reason this happens is because the video url isn't actually the "file with path Url"
So the solution is easy, in the didFinishPicking :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
 guard let mediaInfo = info[.mediaType] else { return }
 let mediaType = "\(mediaInfo)"
 if mediaType == "public.movie" {
    // how we handle it if it's a video
    guard let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? NSURL else {return }
    videoUrl = videoURL.filePathURL as? NSURL // this is the only thing I changed cause this is the file we are uploading
  }
}
```

Thanks for all the help though! even though it didn't help whatsoever.